# Makefile and lvgl

Tags: makefile, stm32, lvgl

My program was generated by stm32CubeMX and i work in vscode. I have a problem with implementation of lvgl in my makefile.

Regarding to the documentation i should add these things to the makefile what i did [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xaxj3.png) .I have lvgl repository in main catalog, and  lv_conf was configured. I'm trying to call function lv_init(). Terminal gives me only this information: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyXnb.png). Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add code and error messages as text and not as images. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors